# Android don't response with HTTP request

Tags: android, api, http, request, response

I have and app make many HTTP request all of them don't have any response in android device ,when i made same request in virtual device or in postman it get's data successfully ,i will put my API example link here if someone want test it.

```
https://technosat-iq.com/myexpect/api/controller/matchs/show_matchs.php?s_id=1
```

How can i solve it ?

Comment: Please check if you've added internet permission in manifest or not.

Comment: opps how i forget that ,I will check ,many time we forgot very simple things

Comment: @shafayathossain Thanks alot ,i forgot to do that :(

Comment: My pleasure. I've answered it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add internet permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

in manifest.xml.